I'm facing an issue while inserting a text data field into a Catalyst Datastore
I couldn't able to insert a text field datatype using Catalyst Rest API from postman. I am facing the below error. This is the example Json data, i'm trying to pass as a input parameter.
{"status":"failure","data":{"message":"The input value is not readable. Please check your input","error_code":"INVALID_INPUT"}}
Kindly help us to resolve this issue.

Where's the error? Or is the error that JSON? And if is, where is the input json.

The error "The input value is not readable" you are getting while inserting a data into a table is due to passing a non JSON value as a input parameter. Hence, you are facing this issue. kindly check the JSON data you are passing whether the input value is in the correct JSON format or not. You can check on their help documentation here for the same.
